# Multiple new browser windows from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have read through many threads here relating to my issue. My problem seems simple, but I cant find the final piece, or I'm just overlooking something obvious. I have found multiple answers, but none that I can get to work. I am simply trying to open 4 new Chrome windows, not tabs. I am almost there. What I am using will in fact open each one up and size and position it. But it is requiring me to close one down before the next one will start.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --window-position=1920,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL 2" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --window-position=1280,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 3" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --window-position=1920,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 4"
exit
```

I have also tried a second bat file, and it will open 4 windows and size them, and does not require me to kill the browser window before the next one will start, but it is ignoring the positioning, so they all just stack on top of each other.

```
@echo off
start chrome --new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL"
start chrome --new-window --window-position=1920,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL 2"
start chrome --new-window --window-position=1280,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 3"
start chrome --new-window --window-position=1920,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 4"
exit
```

What am I missing? I will use either method if someone can just help get me that last yard. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK that's a google chrome *feechur* that you can only overcome by using different profiles for each window instance.

Comment: What seems interesting is that your top batch file works as you want it to, but only if you already have a chrome window open before running it..  If you don't, it waits for closure before opening the next one (as you describe).

Comment: Confirmed - if you have no chrome windows open, the commandline to open a new window doesn't return until you close the window.  If you already had a window open, it returns immediately

Comment: mcr, yes you are correct, just having a Chrome window up and then running the first batch does correct the issue of having to close one down before the next one opens. But that then mimics the second batch file and they all just open up cascading on top of the first random one. Its just ignoring the positioning completely. Frustrating,

Comment: Looks like it's just remembering your last window state from the previous Chrome window.  If you last had Chrome window open maximised, it opens the next one Maximised too - the size and position are correct if you hit the restore button.

Comment: Well PA your comment seemed to work. Tedious as it my be. I created 3 new profiles, by simply copying the default and added them into the second batch. So its look like; 
    @echo off
    start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"--new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL"
    start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\user2"--new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL 2"


Thanks. I'll leave this open for another day or so just in case.

Comment: Sorry that came out sloppy. Suffice it to say, adding the --user-data-dir= with the new profiles worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to user PA in the comments section. So this issue appears to be a quirk of Chrome. Its a bit tedious, especially if you want to do this with several windows. But I created 4 profiles in Chrome and then called them each in the batch. This resolved the issue.

```
@echo off
start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"--new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL"
start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\user2" --new-window --window-position=1920,0 --window-size=640,512 "URL 2"
start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\user3"--new-window --window-position=1280,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 3"
start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\user4"--new-window --window-position=1920,512 --window-size=640,512 "URL 4"
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create adhoc temporary profiles in tmp:

```
REM example for a 4k Monitor
start chrome --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrTmp~%RANDOM%" --new-window --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1934,1086 "https://www.google.com"
start chrome --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrTmp~%RANDOM%" --new-window --window-position=1920,0 --window-size=1934,1086 "https://www.DuckDuckGo.com"
start chrome --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrTmp~%RANDOM%" --new-window --window-position=0,1080 --window-size=1934,1086 "https://www.yahoo.com"
start chrome --user-data-dir="%tmp%\chrTmp~%RANDOM%" --new-window --window-position=1920,1080 --window-size=1934,1086 "https://www.Dogpile.com"
```