# Want to open multiple ie tabs utilizing at least 3 different instances w/ batch file

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

What im attempting to do is create a bat file that auto loads every program that I use at work via normal startup. As of now, upon logging into my system I am able to run a desktop cleanup program, open up the 3 different instances of internet explorer, and the few other dedicated programs I use on a daily basis. What I would love to be able to do would be the open individual tabs within those instances.

For example (these are random sites, not the ones I would use)

```
Instance 1
    www.google.com
    www.yahoo.com
    www.ebay.com

Instance 2
    www.nytimes.com
    www.foxnews.com
    www.wallstreetjournal.com

Instance 3
    www.fidelity.com
    www.marketwatch.com
```

Im assuming if this code was successfully created adding more or less instances/tabs would be easy.

Please keep in mind as it is a work terminal my access to administrator functions is limited.

I figured the best way to get this solved was to reach out to the pros! So what do you think? Can this be done?

Comment: As far as I can remember, there is a IE command line switch `-new`, telling IE to open a new instance (can't test it right now); so `iexplore -new http://www.your_url.net/` should open a new IE window, where the same but omitting `-new` shouldn't (adds a new tab instead); however, I don't know how to tell IE which instance to use to add a new tab to (I think there's no guarantee that the most recently opened instance is used);

Comment: Unfortunately, `-new` option considered [obsolete as of Internet Explorer 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm afraid that [batch-file] is not sufficient for your task. Check [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31451038/3439404) in [VBScript], or switch to [powershell].

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you really want to use a batch file, this code might work.
I tested this on Windows 8.1 where Internet explorer is installed in `c:\program files(x86)\Internet Explorer\`

Copy and paste in a .bat file:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.google.com/"  
ping -n 2 localhost >nul  
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.yahoo.com/"  
ping -n 2 localhost >nul  
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.ebay.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which browser, so here's one for chrome, opera edge and Firefox!

```
@echo off

start chrome -new-window www.google.com www.yahoo.com www.ebay.com
TIMEOUT /T 2
start opera -new-window www.nytimes.com www.foxnews.com www.wallstreetjournal.com
TIMEOUT /T 2
start msedge -new-window www.fidelity.com www.marketwatch.com
TIMEOUT /T 2
start firefox www.snapchat.com www.facebook.com
```

What this does is open chrome in a new window (in case you already have chrome open), and then loads that new window with the list of URLs that come after.

Then opera, then edge (if you must)

For Firefox, it opens *each* URL in a new window, so I removed the new window command, however that means if you have FF already open, it will use that window to open these tabs in...

You can also specify size and position, but **only** by using lots of fake profiles.

[Multiple new browser windows from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592190/multiple-new-browser-windows-from-batch-file/31594446#31594446)